# Dictionary as DataMember in WCF after installing .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012

After installing .NET Framework 4.5 with Visual Studio 2012, whenever I want to obtain the reference from a WCF service, my dictionaries are changed into arrays. For example, `Dictionary<int, double>` is changed into `ArrayOfKeyValueOfintdoubleKeyValueOfintdouble`.

This happens in both Visual Studio 2012 and 2010 (both Express).

I've reviewed my configuration and the dictionary data type in the service reference configuration is `System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary`. Changing this doesn't make a difference.

Reverting to just using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 is not an option.

Comment: This really belongs on SO and I've voted to migrate.  A good rule of thumb is if you are asking a question in front of your IDE it belongs on SO. If you are in front of a white board it belongs on Programmers.

Comment: Thanks @Walter. How do I migrate it? Just delete and ask again?

Comment: @MauricioUlate - NO!  Click on the flag button for moderator attention and then indicate "other" so you can type in the request for migration.

Comment: @Mauricio, I am unable to repro this. My contract looked something like this. Am I missing something? [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Dictionary<int, double> GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
    }
    
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<int, double> BoolValue
        {
            get { return new Dictionary<int, double>(); }
            set {  }
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks @Praburaj. I looked into this and found the following. When I obtain the reference from a web forms project, I get the `System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary` type. If I do this in a MVC4 project, I get a `ArrayOfKeyValueOfintdoubleKeyValueOfintdouble` type.

Comment: Add service reference in MVC4 project template + VS 2012 has a known issue as documented here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2012/08/23/add-service-reference-adding-empty-reference-cs-in-mvc-4-projects-of-vs-2012.aspx. I doubt if you are encountering a similar one. Could you try the work around suggested in this blog and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: @MauricioUlate, did that work for you?

Comment: @Praburaj. Thanks for your answers and ideas. That didn't work. I'm rolling back to MVC2 and Visual Studio 2010 and stay there for a couple of months more to wait for a new version. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MauricioUlate, I tried to reproduce this again on an MVC4 project. Working around the known issue I can successfully generate the service reference. Would you mind sending us a quick repro project to  netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com for us to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this was requested as a migrate I am already here and I can type up a answer.  You need to tell your service reference what type of data structure you want to use. By default Visual Studio uses an Array for services.

Right click on your service reference and choose `Configure Service Reference...`

Under the `Data Type` section you'll see Collection type, there choose the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks @CoffeeMuncher for your answer. Unfortunately, I've tried that unsuccessfully. Like Praburaj pointed out, it seems to be a bug with the MVC4 projects. I've identified the problem when you install VS2012, which updates .NET Framework 4.0 to a new version, which fails to build the reference correctly.